# Count names in alphabetical order in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to count names of employees in alphabetical order  from employees table in HR schema (oracle)

Example..

```
Last_name with.     Count
A.                  4
B.                  3
...
...
Z.                  5
```

How the query will look like..

Comment: Did you try anything. If yes, can you please add the code.

Comment: SUBSTRING, GROUP BY, COUNT()

Comment: @jarlh [`SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679) is the Oracle function to get a substring.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do:

```
select SUBSTR(name,1,1) as name,count(1) as CNT from YOURTABLE

group by SUBSTR(name,1,1)

order by name
```

Comment: The function you want is `SUBSTR` not `SUBSTRING` and you also need `ORDER BY SUBSTR(name,1,1)` to get the alphabetical order.